# Change Apache domain name in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, apache-2.2, server-settings

First time setting up full Apache, on home system for testing, version 2.2

I can't find where to change the domain name, assuming I may have set it wrong at install.

The httpd.conf file doesn't have a specific listing for domain.

Comment: I can't believe someone thinks this is off-topic.  Just cause my Apache-foo is weak.

Comment: Make that two people. It's not off topic cause you couldn't figure out Apache. That part is fine. It's off topic due to being about a home machine. Serverfault is by and for professional systems and network administrators, not home users. This will likely be automatically migrated to Superuser, where this question will be on-topic.

Comment: @ErikA,I'm an admin, who is trying to setup stuff on his home machine to test it out.  They could have looked at my other questions to know that.  It will be wrongly placed on SuperUser, and I will certainly flag it there to migrate.  I really hate the on-SF-must-look-like-an-admin snobbery.  I've spent many many hours trying to google all this Apache stuff before I came here for this one specific point.

Comment: Lance, it's not about snobbery. It's about organization. Even with the fact that you're an admin, this was clearly an end-user type question, and there's *nothing* wrong with that. If I (or any other of the mods or 10k users) mistakenly asked a question on SF about, say, running a chat server on our home networks, it would like get migrated as well, and rightly so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `ServerName` directive